# How to detect autocorrect state of UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

How can I tell whether `UITextView` is in autocorrecting state? That is, the incorrect or incomplete part is highlighted and the candidate is popped up.

Neither `selectedRange` nor `markedTextRange` is useful for this.

Comment: +1 My initial thoughts went to UITextInputTraits, but that only specifies autocorrectionType... This is tough.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could force the autocorrect to be applied and then check to see if there are any changes (a modified version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012198/953105), however that will destroy the autocorrect suggestion. I'm not sure of your use case, but that could work.