# How to dismiss/detect NSTextView text replacement/substitution popup

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I have an NSTextView which has text replacement enabled and as expected it pops up suggestions as can be seen in the following:

[image: Text suggestion popup]

Question I have is - how do I detect that this is visible and how can I dismiss it programmatically. Simply setting first responder somewhere else doesn't do the trick. Indeed it ends the edit and leaves the popup still visible.

Thanks

Comment: Seems similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217805/how-can-i-programmatically-dismiss-the-autocorrect-popover-in-a-uitextview

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'm on OSX and the suggestion there (unmarkText) doesn't have any effect. However, if I hack it by doing something like             [self.textView.textStorage setAttributedString:self.textView.textStorage]; then it clears the popup. Not nice though - must be a better way?

Comment: NSTextViewDelegate's textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:and textViewDidChangeSelection: ??  Or maybe subclass textView and override complete: to just set a flag you can monitor?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am trying to figure out how to have text replacements appear in the suggestion box like that.  When I create a toy app using a default NSTextView, text replacement is performed (e.g. `short` is converted to `long`), but it happens without displaying the popup.  Typing slowly or quickly doesn't change this.  Building TextEdit from source, however, does show the popups. But I can't identify the relevant code in TextEdit...  Any pointers??  Thanks!